# encryption using provided key using DES with padding

Tags: java, encryption, padding, des

I want to encrypt a frame using DES using a given key.

The padding style I am using is PKCS5Padding. This pads the string with 02 02 if 2 bytes are to be added and with 03 03 03 if 3 bytes are to be added to make multiple of 8.
But my requirement is to pad a string with my particular bytes. e.g if 2 bytes are to be added then 30 30 and 3 bytes are to be added then 30 30 30 (in hex 0's value is 30). Also, I must know how many padded bytes have been added.
Which padding technique should I follow and how can I use it?

Below is my code for encryption:

```
byte[] keyValue = new byte[]{(byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x16,(byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x12};
myKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(keyValue);
mySecretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
key = mySecretKeyFactory.generateSecret(myKeySpec);


Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
IvParameterSpec iv2 = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv2);
byte[] plainText = function.HexStringToByteArray(payloadRecv);
byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not select `PKCS5Padding` in the cipher specification. Select `NoPadding`. You'll have to add the padding onto the data yourself prior to encrypting it. After decrypting it (also using no padding), you'll have to inspect the last byte to know how many bytes of padding to remove and remove it yourself.

Basically, just code exactly what you described.

Comment: That's correct, but I hope that your data does not end with 30h, because it won't be possible to distinquish data and padding. I've never heard of the padding mechanism the asker describes, so it won't be included in any crypto API.

Comment: @Robert: well yes, if you always add padding there will be padding. How does that relate to my comment?

Comment: @Robert: Whatever padding scheme is used, it must allow the decryptor to distinguish between real data and padding. If the real data ends in 30H then how could you tell where the real data ends and the padding begins? Suppose the decryptor decrypts the last block and see 30H 30H. Which bytes are padding and which are data?

Comment: If I understand the original question correctly, he determines the number of bytes of padding to be added, and then sets the value of each byte to 16 times that number. So if the last byte is `0x40`, then there are 4 bytes of padding.