# java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid key length: 8 bytes

Tags: java, 3des

I have requirement where I am having a hex key-1122334455667788 and 
hex message-2962A83E5D3D5187 to decode with 3des. But when i am trying to decode it ,I am getting error "java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid key length: 8 bytes".Please anybody can help?

My code to decrypt

```
public class TripleDES {

    public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                                 + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    byte[] keyBytes=hexStringToByteArray("1122334455667788");
    byte[] message=hexStringToByteArray("2962A83E5D3D5187");
     final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
        final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
        final Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

        // final byte[] encData = new
        // sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(message);
        final byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(message);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A triple-DES key is 24 bytes long; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/DESedeKeySpec.html.

(I would try padding the byte array to 24 bytes with zero bytes at the start or end ... and see what works for your cypher text.)

---

Next problem ...

> I tried to change the key to
>
> ```
>   String desKey = "000000000000000000000000000000001122334455667788";
> ```
>
> but I am now getting a "Given final block not properly padded" exception.

I think that is saying that the message is not padded correctly.   Try using "NoPadding" instead of "PKCS5Padding".

See

- [encryption using provided key using DES with padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634065/encryption-using-provided-key-using-des-with-padding)

Comment: I tried to change the key to String desKey = "000000000000000000000000000000001122334455667788";  but getting "Given final block not properly padded" exception

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class DESede {

    private static Cipher encryptCipher;
    private static Cipher decryptCipher;

    private static byte[] encryptData(String data) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        System.out.println("Data Before Encryption :" + data);
        byte[] dataToEncrypt = data.getBytes();
        byte[] encryptedData = encryptCipher.doFinal(dataToEncrypt);
        System.out.println("Encryted Data: " + encryptedData);
        return encryptedData;
    }

    private static void decryptData(byte[] data) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        byte[] textDecrypted = decryptCipher.doFinal(data);
        System.out.println("Decryted Data: " + new String(textDecrypted));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeySpecException {
        try {

            String desKey = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef"; // Key from user
            byte[] keyBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(desKey);
            System.out.println((int) keyBytes.length);

            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
            SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(new DESedeKeySpec(keyBytes));

            encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key); // throwing Exception
            byte[] encryptedData = encryptData("Confidential Data");
            decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            byte iv[] = encryptCipher.getIV(); 
            IvParameterSpec dps = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, dps);
            decryptData(encryptedData);

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

DESede need 24 bytes key. Try this program.

**OUTPUT**

```
Data Before Encryption :Confidential Data
Encryted Data: [B@6fadae5d
Decryted Data: Confidential Data
```

Comment: I have modified the code and used as i already have the encrypted data(in hex format) and the key(in hex format) to decrypt data.But I am getting error  "Given final block not properly padded". I have done this modifiaction    String desKey = "000000000000000000000000000000001122334455667788";       byte[] encryptedData = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("2962A83E5D3D5187");

Comment: If your key and message is in hex format skip parseHexBinary in the above program.

Comment: I converted my key and encrypted data in hex to byte array using public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                                 + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }  but still getting same exception

Comment: What data are you encrypted ?

Comment: I am having an encrypted data "2962A83E5D3D5187" and a key "1122334455667788".I need to decrypt this data using this key

Comment: Again. Which algorithm and size of the key used for encryption.

Comment: 3DES algorithm is used to encrypt the data and key is "1122334455667788".I tried decrypting the data using this online tool "http://tripledes.online-domain-tools.com" and getting the correct data.But unable to decrypt data using my code

Comment: In which mode it is encrypted. Do you have the encryption code?

Comment: It's getting encrypted in ECB and i don't have the encryption code

Comment: @AnkurSrivastava I decrypted your message. I got "FB" is it correct ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class TripleDES {

    public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = hexStringToByteArray("1122334455667788");
        byte[] message = hexStringToByteArray("2962A83E5D3D5187");
        final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DES");
        final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
        final Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
        decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        final byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(message);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Data :: "+new String(plainText));
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Decrypted Data :: FB
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate answer?

Comment: So why do you have two answers?   Why don't you combine them?

Comment: Ankur didn't responded yet. I wil remove one later.